# SAP Javascript ENTER button does not work

Tags: javascript, enter, sap-bsp

I have an application developed in javascript and adopted in SAP (BSP).

After system copy ENTER button is not working in system - when I change the data it is endless looping the loading.

code fragment for enter function:

```
function Enter(keycode) {
if (window.event.srcElement.type == "textarea" && keycode == 13 ) {
glLastKeycode = keycode;
keycode = 0;
} else {
glLastKeycode = keycode;
}
if (keycode == 13) {
write_wait();
window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(document.forms[0]);
document.forms[0].elements['event'].value='SPEICHERN';
document.forms[0].submit();
```

the picture how it is processing in app:

1. change quantity
2. ENTER button press
   [image: image description]

Comment: What are the first and last statement of the endless loop? (Does it reach the statement after `document.forms[0].submit()` or is it this statement which executes the `Enter` function again? Then, how is the `Enter` function linked to an event?) How is this Javascript question related to SAP software?

Comment: 1) it is the statement which executes the function ENTER.
2) External application , SAP BSP element is developed in javascript.

P.S.
I can not get why loading process is just endless. I can not see and catch any inconsistency in fragment.

I have tested different ways, nothing helps.